# Getting a segfault- trying to retrieve data from my struct

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault

I'm having trouble understanding why I'm getting a segfault in my code. I'm just trying to store data in my array of nodes and wanted to see if my data was getting stored properly.

```
#define BLOCK_SIZE 256
#define MAX_NAME_LENGTH 128
#define DATA_SIZE 254
#define INDEX_SIZE 127

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum
{
   DIR, 
   FILE, 
   INDEX,
   DATA
} NODE_TYPE;

char *bitvector; // allocate space for managing 2^16 blocks (in init)         (size is 8192)

typedef struct data_t
{
   int size;
   void *data;
} data_t;

typedef struct fs_node
{
   char name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
   time_t creat_t; // creation time
   time_t access_t; // last access
   time_t mod_t; // last modification
   mode_t access; // access rights for the file
   unsigned short owner; // owner ID
   unsigned short size;
   unsigned short block_ref; // reference to the data or index block
} FS_NODE;

typedef struct node
{
   NODE_TYPE type;
   union
   {
      FS_NODE fd;
  data_t data[DATA_SIZE];
  unsigned short index[INDEX_SIZE];
   } content;
} NODE;

// storage blocks
NODE *memory; // allocate 2^16 blocks (in init)

void init()
{
   memory = malloc(sizeof(NODE) * 65536);
   memory[0].type = DIR;

   FS_NODE *root = malloc(sizeof(FS_NODE));
   strcpy(root->name,"/");
   root->creat_t = 0;
   root->access_t = 0;
   root->mod_t = 0;
   root->access = 0400;
   root->owner = 0;
   root->size = 0;
   root->block_ref = 1;

   memory[0].content.fd = *root;
}

int main()
{
   printf("%s\n", memory[0].content.fd.name);
   free(memory);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `memory` object was not allocated before you used it...

Change this

```
int main() {
  printf("%s\n", memory[0].content.fd.name);
  free(memory);
  return 0;
}
```

to this

```
int main() {
  init();
  printf("%s\n", memory[0].content.fd.name);
  free(memory);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am an ****** I've been going trhough gbd and didn't see anything set lol... Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

1. there is no function call init() in your main() function.
2. there should be free memory for (   FS_NODE *root = malloc(sizeof(FS_NODE));).